# Divs inline aren't aligned vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navbar with a button and an icon of an hamburger menu. I put both divs inline but they risulted disaligned vertically. I can't find the mistake. What did I do wrong?

```css
html, body{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
        }
   .riga{
     display: block;
     }
  .bg_grigio{
      background-color: gray;
         }
  .testo_a_destra{
      text-align: right;
       }
  .pulsante{
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
     }
 .verde_vuoto{
     border: 2px solid #0a5537;
     background-color: inherit;
     }
 .div_inlinea{
     display: inline;
     margin-left: 40px;
    }
 .icona img{
    width: 4%;
    }
 #riga_logo{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="riga_logo" class="riga bg_grigio">
  <div class="testo_a_destra">
    <div class="pulsante verde_vuoto div_inlinea">Order Benugo Delivery</div>
    <div class="icona div_inlinea"><img src="Images/menu.png" alt="menu_icon" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAJcH.jpg)

Comment: for one I would use flex-box here. for two its hard to tell because in your example image is missing, and from your screenshot it seems that image is higher than nav bar causing this. Try adding specific height to img css.

Comment: They are aligned, https://snipboard.io/zgZlwq.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I tried to use flexbox and I tried also to add specific height to the img and now they are aligned.